# QuickConverter XAML- failed to tokenize expression

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have an `Expander` whose visibility is determined by the items present in a `CollectionViewSource`. While the XAML compiles and works, I end up with warning message as below and any help in understanding how to get rid of the error is much appreciated.

*"Error Failed to tokenize expression "$P.View.Count > 0 ? Visibility.Visible: Visibility.Collapsed". Did you forget a '$'?"*

```
<Expander 
    IsExpanded="True"
    Visibility="{qc:Binding '$P.View.Count > 0 ? Visibility.Visible: Visibility.Collapsed', P={Binding ACollectionViewSource}}"
 >
```

Comment: What library does `qc:Binding` come from?  That is definitely *not* standard WPF binding syntax.

Comment: Looking at that syntax, you *may* need to encode the `>` as `&gt;`, so it doesn't mess with the markup extension.

Comment: @BradleyUffner qc - QuickConverter https://www.nuget.org/packages/QuickConverter/

I've resorted to defining a converter(integerToVisibility) to avoid the errors shown in the XAML editor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can only reference types in the QuickConverter syntax once you've explicitly registered the namespace and/or assembly containing that type:

```
QuickConverter.EquationTokenizer
              .AddNamespace(typeof(System.Windows.Visibility));
```

It also appears that QuickConverter will not hook up property change listeners for properties referenced *inside* the tokenized equation, so you'll need to pass in the observable property directly.

```
Visibility="{qc:Binding '$P ? Visibility.Collapsed : Visibility.Visible',
                        P={Binding ItemsView.View.IsEmpty}}"
```

Note that I tested `IsEmpty` instead of `Count`, as `Count` does not exist on `ICollectionView`.  Testing `Count` would have worked at runtime, but the property would have been flagged as unresolved in the Xaml editor.